# DefaultFriendlyURLMapper bug on Liferay 6.2.1 with wildfly 8

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, wildfly

I've added a message board portlet and created a category. When I clicked on the category, portlet didn't display.
In logs I found error

> Invalid path was requested %2Fmessage_boards%2Fview.

The problem is with `DefaultFriendlyURLMapper`, because when I remove `friendly-url-mapping` in `liferay-portlet.xml` for the message board, portlet works.

This error is also in other portlets, I've tried asset publisher.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that Undertow (Wildfly) and JBoss Web/Tomcat does not implement the servlet API the same way. Undertow is not decoding parameter in the HttpServletRequest unlike JBoss Web/Tomcat. I had the same problem and decided to fix it in Liferay because as you said, it only happens when friendly url requests are being forwarded to the dispatcher.

Have a look at [this patch](https://github.com/samcontesse/liferay-portal/commit/6f3b8982a76d2fa082bae496330d995f6cde49f1) on GitHub. You also probably want to follow [this thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37537492) on Liferay Forum.

Hope it will help.